# friendly url nginx fix

Tags: nginx, friendly-url

I have problem with friendly URLs. The script below is working but not currently like
`/index.php` works
`/index` works
`/index/` doesn't work (I expect it to open the same page as `/index`)
how to fix this?

```
location / {
    autoindex on;
    root   /var/www/plasti;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.php$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    #fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120s;
    #fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `/index/` to do? With your current configuration, URIs with a trailing `/` will invoke the `index` directive, in which case, `nginx` will be looking for URIs matching: `/index/index.php`, `/index/index.html`, or `/index/index.htm`.

Comment: No i just need /index/ works same like /index it's for seo i get errors cuz not working /index/

Comment: You could try adding a rewrite to change the trailing slash: `rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1.php last;`

Comment: Not working this rewrite